# subscript an array having the register storage class

Tags: c, arrays, gnu, c99

In GNU c99 manual:

> 3.13 Array Subscripts
>
> You can access array elements by specifying the name of the array, and
>   the array subscript (or index, or element number) enclosed in
>   brackets. Here is an example, supposing an integer array called
>   my_array:
>
> ```
> my_array[0] = 5;
> ```
>
> The array subscript expression A[i] is defined as
>   being identical to the expression (*((A)+(i))). This means that many
>   uses of an array name are equivalent to a pointer expression. **It also**
>   **means that you cannot subscript an array having the register storage**
>   **class**.

I have tried below things and it is working fine for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        register int arr[10] = {1, [9] = 6};

        printf("arr[9] %d\n", *((arr) + 9)); // working fine
        printf("arr[9] %d\n", arr[9]); //working fine
        return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please explain what is meant by statement in bold letters? Or I tried wrong to validate it.

Comment: Hypothesis: This statement is obsolete, the compiler now largely ignores `register`, and it generates working code even though the C standard might not require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC 8.1 yields:

```
$ gcc rega89.c
rega89.c: In function ‘main’:
rega89.c:7:9: error: address of register variable ‘arr’ requested
         printf("arr[9] %d\n", *((arr) + 9)); // working fine
         ^~~~~~
$
```

That's without any extra options.  In fact, even GCC 4.8.1 complains with no options.  (GCC 8.1 defaults to C11; GCC 4.8.1 defaults to C90; specifying `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` makes no difference.)

So, if you are using GCC, you must be using an older version of GCC than 4.8.1.  Or you are using some other compiler that is not as standard-compliant as GCC is.

Comment: yes!!! i was working on mac and it didn't throw any error. However, when it tried on another system it did report same for me as well.gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5

Comment: Funny – I was testing on a Mac too, but using 'real' GCC, not Clang disguised as GCC.